# Link to Custom list item from Workflow task in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-tasks-list

How to implement a link field in Workflow task to show associated list item. Basically, user should able to open associated list item from workflow task(All tasks view or my task view)

Comment: Doesn't your workflow task have a "related item" field? Mine does. Every time a workflow for an item creates a task, the task has the "related item" link to the item that the workflow was run on.

Comment: Yes i have "related item" field.In all task view,this particular field("Related Item") shows only how many number of the items related to this item.Here i need a link(Hyper link ) for each item to navigate to associate list item.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the task form, use Infopath to edit your task form. From the 'Fields' window. Just drag the 'Related Content' field onto your task form.